# sencha touch tap on search button and load a dataview with ajax search

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, touch

I am almost new to sencha touch and I have this simple question:
I have a panel with a search field and a start search button (a simple search):

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    html: '<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="images/logo.png" style="max-width:40%;" /></div>',

},{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: '<center>Insert your adress</center>',
    cls:'ps-red',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'adress',
        required: true,
        clearIcon: true,
    }]
},{
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Search',
    ui:'confirm-round',
    margin:5,
    handler:function(){
    }
}]
```

Clicking on the search button I need to make an ajax call  with the input text params, and display results to another panel. **What should I write in the handler function of the button?**

```
Ext.define('Demo.view.SearchResults', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'resultcard',
    config: {
        layout:'fit',
        cls:'ks-basic',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            cls:        'dataview-basic',
            store:      '????', 
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK let us assume the store as 'SampleStore'

this is the sample call that you should write in handler function, see if it is useful to you,in this example I added push view, you can update panel if you want

```
      handler : function(){
             var navigationView = button.up('navigationview');
             Ext.getStore('SampleStore').getProxy().setExtraParam('search',address);
             Ext.getStore('SampleStore').load({
               callback: function(record, operation, success) {
                  if(success && record.length) {
                    // here you can call any other function to update panel
                   navigationView.push({
                     xtype  : 'resultcard',
                     record : record
                   });
                  }  else {
                  Ext.Msg.alert('Address not found. (' + address + ')');
                  }
               }
           });
        }// handler close
```

Comment: Hi gigi, thank you for the answer but I already solved speding some days. Anyway the setExtraParam you show here is need to me